# TextView keeps popping up

Tags: android, animation, textview

I have an activity where an TextView show up, and after that it fades out. However, everytime it has fade out, it pops back in.  I tried

```
wtext.setText("");
```

But then my text just disappeares without fading out(after fading in). Does anyone knows how to fix this? Thanks! Kind regards.

This is my code:

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {



protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

    Handler handler = new Handler();

    final TextView wtext = (TextView) (findViewById(R.id.wtext));

    Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.abc_fade_in);
    wtext.startAnimation(animation);

    Runnable task = new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Animation animation1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.abc_fade_out);
                    wtext.startAnimation(animation1);
                    wtext.setText("");
                }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(task, 5000);
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want something to happen after an animation is complete (in this case, hide a textview), you'll have to use an [AnimationListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html)

```
Animation.AnimationListener myListener = new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                wtext.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }

        };
animation1.setAnimationListener(myListener);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [ViewPropertyAnimator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#animate()), which will change the view's actual properties rather than just its appearance, so that it will not jump back to the original state after the animation is complete.

```
wtext.animate().alpha(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting **fillAfter** flag to **true** on the element: it will apply the final transformation to it after the animation is finished.